# Test spring configuration with ConditionalOnCloudPlatform annotation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to test my Spring configuration class which is annotated with `ConditionalOnCloudPlatform`.

Here is a very simplified example of the configuration class (I can't post my actual code):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnCloudPlatform(CloudPlatform.CLOUD_FOUNDRY)
public class CloudConfigurationExample {
  @Bean
  public MyBean myBean(MyProperties properties) {
    return new MyBean(properties.getParam);
  }
}
```

To test I was hoping to do this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CloudConfigurationExampleTest {
  private CloudConfigurationExample cloudConfigurationExample;
  private MyProperties myProperties;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    myProperties = new MyProperies();
    myProperties.setParam("test");
    cloudConfigurationExample = new CloudConfigurationExample(myProperties);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    MyBean myBean = cloudConfigurationExample.myBean();
    // do asserts etc.
  }

}
```

The issue I have is that `ConditionalOnCloudPlatform` is activated and expects a valid cloud connector to be present. As a result I get `No suitable cloud connector found`.

Does anyone know the correct way so get Junit to ignore this annotation? I tried setting an environment variable with `VCAP_SERVICES`, which is what this annotation expects, but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> ConditionalOnCloudPlatform gets activated if environment contains properties **VCAP_APPLICATION** and **VCAP_SERVICES**

There are different ways to overcome this issue,

Firstly, ensure no properties containing above prefixes are passed. 
Secondly, check for cloud profile `@Profile("cloud")` or ignore this class during test `@Profile("!test")` and many more ways.

code snippet:

```
CLOUD_FOUNDRY {

        @Override
        public boolean isActive(Environment environment) {
            return environment.containsProperty("VCAP_APPLICATION")
                    || environment.containsProperty("VCAP_SERVICES");
        }

    },
```